# angularJS cant find provider, and neither can I

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I recently deployed some code to our site, and a page that was not touched got an error. I cannot reproduce the error on my local machine, and to make matters worse the error makes no sense. Here is the error

Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: stationProvider <- station <- RSViewController

Here is my entire RSViewController:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('packerapp.retail-shipment')
    .controller('RSViewController', RSViewController);

/* @ngInject */
function RSViewController(shipmentView, orderView, loggedInUser) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.shipmentView = shipmentView;
    vm.orderView = orderView;

    activate();

    function activate() {

    }
}
})();
```

The word station is not even in the page or any page near it. I couldn't find anywhere it would even want a station provider.

Any idea where to look?

Comment: could you please shed some light on where you got this error from?
could it be that you're seeing other application's errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!

My coworker made another controller with the same name as my controller. So there were two 'RSViewController's. So when the one was called the other one was called as well, and this broke everything for just that one page.